# Best method for building models using cumulative autocorrelated data

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

context:
As an example, say I am trying to find the causes of maintenance on a vehicle using its use. With an ultimate aim of understanding the relationship between the two.

If I only have variables such as hours of highway use and say hours of maintenance on a given day. You cannot know which specific hour of highway use caused the maintenance hours. As such, I would accumulate highway hours for each day. If I drive 10 hours a day, it will be presented as (10,20, 30 etc). This would ensure that every hour is taken into account once a maintenance event occurs. Maintenance hours would equally be accumulate over time.

I can run a GLM on this and receive reasonable coefficients, significant results. But this all violates the fundamentals of regression requiring independence of predictors. Yet, I cannot see what an alternative approach in this scenario would be? For every new highway use hour or maintenance hour, its impact would be less. Are the Betas irrelevant in this model? Would a beta of 0.01 on driving hours, meaning 100 driving hours for 1 maintenance hour be wrong? Would adding time to the model, control for the accumulation? what would be the best approach here?